# Observable loses value after call to applyBindings

Tags: knockout.js

I am working on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StrandedPirate/yjhz6bvj/) trying to isolate a problem I'm having with the value not being set on a `select` element and now I'm stuck with nonsensical behavior in jsfiddle. I can't tell if this issue is my underlying problem or if this is a bug in jsfiddle.

First I'm using inheritance with my view models as described here: [Using Super Constructors Is Critical In Prototypal Inheritance In Javascript](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1566-using-super-constructors-is-critical-in-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript.htm) . Perhaps this article has led me down the wrong path, I don't know. Bottom line is that I need to do inheritance.

Second the problem with this particular fiddle is that after the call to `ko.applyBindings` my observable just loses its value (becomes `undefined`) and then out of no where gets set to `1`.

[image]

```
function userAddressModelBase(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.states = ko.observableArray(data.states);
}

userAddressModel.prototype = new userAddressModelBase({});
userAddressModel.constructor = userAddressModel;

function userAddressModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    userAddressModelBase.call(self, data);

    self.sampleText = ko.observable("i'm here");

    console.log("data.selectedStateId is: " + data.selectedStateId);
    self.selectedStateId = ko.observable(data.selectedStateId);
    console.log("self.selectedStateId is: " + self.selectedStateId());

    self.getStates = function () {
        console.log("getStates running...");
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("getStates callback...");
            self.states([new stateModel({
                id: 1,
                name: "New York"
            }), new stateModel({
                id: 2,
                name: "Texas"
            }), new stateModel({
                id: 3,
                name: "California"
            }), new stateModel({
                id: 4,
                name: "Ohio"
            })]);
            console.log(ko.toJS(self));
            console.log("getStates callback self.selectedStateId is: " + self.selectedStateId());
        }, 1000);
    };

    //console.log("self.selectedStateId is: " + self.selectedStateId());
    //self.getStates();
    //console.log("self.selectedStateId is: " + self.selectedStateId());
}

function stateModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}

var model = new userAddressModel({ selectedStateId: 3 });

console.log(ko.toJS(model));
console.log("before applyBindings model.selectedStateId is: " + model.selectedStateId());
console.log("appling bindings...");
ko.applyBindings(model); // selectedStateId is now undefined!!!
console.log("appling bindings finished.");
console.log(ko.toJS(model));

console.log("after applyBindings model.selectedStateId is: " + model.selectedStateId());
model.getStates(); // selectedStateId is now 1 after this finishes!!!
```

Comment: what exactly is the question? Your fiddle seems to be working as expected - what's the problem there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes you think that your `selectedStateId` should have a value? Sure you set it initially with one value but when everything has had a chance to load and bind, it doesn't mean it has to keep that value.

That observable is bound to the value of an empty `select` dropdown.  With no values available, what else is supposed to be selected?  Only later on do you fill the select with some values so now you have a value.

If you wanted to preserve that value, you need to make sure that it is not empty by the time you apply the bindings or set the value.

Comment: I assumed knockout would preserve the initial value until the options were populated; clearly not the case. I've resolved by setting the selected option after all options have been retrieved.